# In Parse.com JS SDK, how to delete an element from inside an array of pointers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

Not the best moment to ask for a Parse.com question, but I have to keep working with parse for some months. Here is my question:

In Parse.com I'm using the Javascript SDK. 
I have an **array** of pointers to class User:

`[{userObject1.id}, {userObject2.id}, {userObject3.id}]`

how can I delete for example object {userObject2} from **inside of the array** when I just have the id of the object I want to remove?

Currently I'm removing the inside object by doing a **forEach** loop using array.splice(indexDelete, 1);. I'm looking for better solution.

```
var wasSomethingDeleted = 0;
var MyParseFollow = Parse.Object.extend('Follow');
var query = new Parse.Query(MyParseFollow);
query.equalTo("user", channelUser); // fetch all followers
query.first().then(
    function (Follow) {
        if (Follow){
            if (Follow.get("followedBy").length > 0){ // check if there is any follower
                var listOfFollowers = Follow.get("followedBy"); // get the array of userObjects of followers
                var indexDelete = 0;
                listOfFollowers.forEach(function(user){
                    if( user.id == Parse.User.current().id ){ // I want to remove the current authenticated user
                        wasSomethingDeleted++;
                        listOfFollowers.splice(indexDelete, 1); // remove the element
                    }else{
                        indexDelete++;
                    }
                });
                if( wasSomethingDeleted > 0 ){
                    Follow.set('followedBy', listOfFollowers); // save new updated array list of followers
                    Follow.save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I just got this email from Parse.com http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/ They are shutting down the service. It may not answer your question but perhaps it means you nolonger need an answer.

Comment: Parse is around until 2017, and Parse has open-sourced their server. I imagine somewhat of a strong community backing of the open sourced code for some years to come.

Comment: They have open-sourced their server but the whole point of using Parse.com was that you didn't have to run your own server.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation of Parse js guide.Try this

```
var wasSomethingDeleted = 0;
var MyParseFollow = Parse.Object.extend('Follow');
var query = new Parse.Query(MyParseFollow);
query.equalTo("user", channelUser); // fetch all followers
query.first().then(
    function (Follow) {
        if (Follow){
            if (Follow.get("followedBy").length > 0){ // check if there is any follower
                    Follow.remove('followedBy', {Parse.User.current().id}); //remove all instances of the current user from followedBy field.
                    Follow.save();
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do..  using 2 query for user and your class in order to remove just one user object from the array.

you can test and then adjust in order to add your 'forEach' in list of followers. You can do a forEach loop on the followers, fetch each user object to an Array-of-Users, then call remove on the entire array and in one step they all get remove from the MPFollow.followedBy array.

```
        var qu = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        var _user; 
        var folRequest = Parse.Object.extend("MPFollow");
        var qcr = new Parse.Query(folRequest);

        qu.get(userId).then(function(user) {
          if (typeof user === "undefined") {
            return Parse.Promise.error("DNF user to remove");
          } else{
             _user = user;
            return qcr.get(MPFollowId);
          }
        }).then(function(mpf){

          _mpf = mpf;
          _mpf.remove("followedBy", _user);
            console.log('ChnReq UP rm user : ' + _chan.id + ' ' +      _user.id);
          return _mpf.save();
}).then(function(){
          console.log('remov prcss complete');

        },function(e) {
          console.log('ERR ' + e.code + ' ' +e.message);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion : I think you want to remove current login user from list or if you want remove any user from a list. then why you get it from server and then removing it, you can use this like

```
query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", user.id);
```

this will help you to remove any not needed users.

Answer (score -1):

I belive this should work

```
 var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
 var user = new User();
 user.id = "UserID1";
 user.destroy().then(console.log.bind(console))
```

or

```
 var user = User.createWithoutData("UserID1"); 
 user.destroy().then(console.log.bind(console))
```

Since you have multiple user ids you may want to use [`Parse.Object.destroyAll`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_destroy) method

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't understand how it will help me solving the problem. I understand how to destroy an object User, and I don't want that. I want to remove the user's object from inside of the array, I DO NOT want to destroy it.